# Using React useState in array.map for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set up multiple useStates on dynamically created elements inside an array.map. Every element inside of the array.map should use the same useState, but have its proper value assigned. For example the array.map has 3 different elements, which all should have "focus" set to false. When clicked, the clicked element's useState should change to true, the others should remain false.

```
    const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);
```

```
    { projects.map((project, index) => (
        <div className={` ${focus ? "focus" : ""} `} key={project.id}>
            <div className="cover" to={"/work/" + project.slug} onClick={ () => setFocus(true) }>
            </div>
        </div>
    ))}
```

Comment: One of the most recent topics with the same root cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558319/button-is-expanding-for-all-rows-instead-of-one#comment122947306_69558319

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the `id` of the `project` that should have the `focus`.  A single `boolean` state property isn't going to work.

e.g.

```
const [focusedProject, setFocusedProject] = useState(undefined);
...
onClick={() => setFocusedProject(project.id)}
```

then

```
<div className={` ${focusedProject === project.id ? "focus" : ""} `} key={project.id}>
```

Comment: Ah sure, that's a really logical way of doing it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could change the `className` value to `{project.id == focusedProject && "focus"}` instead of using an ternary operator. There is also no need to nest the expression inside an string template.

Comment: yes thats true, but when needed to add more class names in the future, without the likes of `classnames` library etc, most people turn to template literal strings, as in the original question, and in that case `{project.id == focusedProject && "focus"}` outputs 'false' as one of the class names, which isn't ideal